# Jetpack compose State Hoisting

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose can I use state hoisting and pass down state / setState on multiple composables down the hierarchy (with different packages) ?

I have the following issue:

```
@Composable
fun JetpackComposeApp() {
    var theme by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(ThemeState(isDarkTheme = isDarkTheme))
    }
    ...
    NavHost(...) {
        composable(route = MainNavRoutes.Settings) {
           SettingsScreen(hiltViewModel(it), theme) { newTheme ->
              theme = newTheme
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The above works. SettingsScreen updates whole theme correctly.

But if I refactor Navhost to a different package with arguments (theme, setTheme), setter works but SettingsScreen doesn't get the updated theme. Theme is always the old one.

Is state hoisting limited to something ? Like package / composables optimization ?
Or I am missing something here ?

The above can be found in repo: [link](https://github.com/Vivecstel/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/tree/develop), files: MainActivity, SettingsScreen.

Answer (score 0):

updating/observing state value should work even with deep call stacks, if I understand correctly your problem you should wrap `setTheme` in a  `rememberUpdatedState()` within your `SettingsScreen` and access/hoist this updated value

Comment: thanks:) I will try it like this and let you know.